# How can I optimize query with col IN () and date range?

Tags: mysql, datetime, mariadb, query-optimization

The table structure is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(66) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `insert_date` DATETIME(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `name` (`name`),
    INDEX `insert_date` (`insert_date`)
);
```

The original query is as follows.

```
SELECT *
FROM log AS irl
WHERE irl.name IN (
    'abc', 'bcd', 'etc' .... 
/* Less than 10,000 and can be imported from other tables using subqueries. */ 
)
AND irl.insert_date >= @START_DATE
AND irl.insert_date <= @END_DATE;
```

The number of rows in the log table is at least 10 million and can be in billion units.

The original query is too slow.

If there is a good way, please introduce it.

Comment: Write a stored procedure. First insert agent_key to a virtual table, then rewrite the query using that table.

Comment: @yusufhayırsever sorry it was a type. I just rewrote it

Comment: "imported from other tables using subqueries" - It is likely to be faster to merge the two queries together.

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) and then [edit] your question to give us a bit more information, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try two different compound indexes, one after the other.

```
CREATE INDEX firstOneToTry ON log (name, insert_date);
```

then

```
CREATE INDEX secondOneToTry ON log (insert_date, name);
```

If your query said

```
WHERE irl.name = 'abc' 
  AND irl.insert_date >= @START_DATE
  AND irl.insert_date <= @END_DATE
```

The first index I suggested would be the obvious right choice. But with your selection of multiple `name` values it's not as clear.

And, there's an error in your date filter. Consider using this, with `<` for the end of your date range. Otherwise you won't get any rows from after midnight on your @END_DATE.

```
  AND irl.insert_date >= DATE(@START_DATE)
  AND irl.insert_date <  DATE(@END_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```